# Why does my tableview automatically scroll after reloadData or reloadSection?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using UITableViewAutomaticDimension in estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath. My tableViewCells are having large content in it. When i try to reloadData or reloadSection it automatically scroll up or down. I can not use reloadRow as my action can cause insertion/deletion/reload of certain number of rows in section.

Comment: I am not sure it is related to your issue but `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` is supposed to return a fixed value. It is `heightForRowAtIndexPath` that should return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for supporting self-sizing cells.

Comment: Use that "[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];" after reloading data.

Comment: You might want to look at this answer if you want to keep the scroll position : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40042923/3548469

Comment: Thank @ozgur it helped me a bit. Now while using `reloadData` it does not scroll automatically but some time for my last section footer view of section hides automatically. My tableView style is `UITableViewStylePlain`. Does it relate to this one? And while reloading section it steel scroll down automatically.