# Tableview scrolls to top when adding new data. Infinite scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, tableview

When I scroll to the bottom of my tableview and fetch more data with the next offset, i add the new objects to my data array. My tableview however reloads and returns to the first cell. I'm trying to prevent this.

[image]

[image]

```
- (void)fetchMovies {
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    [self.networkingHelper fetchNowPlayingWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

     if (error) {
         [self showErrorView:self.errorView];
     } else {
         [self hideErrorView:self.errorView];
     }

     [self.movies addObjectsFromArray:objects];
     self.displayedItems = self.movies;

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         self.isMoreDataLoading = false;

         if ([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]){
             NSLog(@"In main thread--completion handler");

             [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
             [self.loadingMoreView stopAnimating];
             [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Not in main thread--completion handler");
         }
         });
       }

     ];
}
```

Edit Tried adding this

```
- (void)fetchMovies {
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    [self.networkingHelper fetchNowPlayingWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
     {

         if (error)
         {
             [self showErrorView:self.errorView];
         }
         else
         {
             [self hideErrorView:self.errorView];

         }
         [self.movies addObjectsFromArray:objects];
         self.displayedItems = self.movies;


         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             self.isMoreDataLoading = false;


             if ([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]){
                 NSLog(@"In main thread--completion handler");

                 CGFloat oldOffset = self.moviesTableView.contentSize.height;
                 [self.moviesTableView reloadData];
                 CGFloat onewOffset = self.moviesTableView.contentSize.height;
                 CGPoint new = CGPointMake(0, onewOffset - oldOffset);

                 [self.moviesTableView setContentOffset:new];

                 [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
                 [self.loadingMoreView stopAnimating];
                 [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];


             }
             else{
                 NSLog(@"Not in main thread--completion handler");
             }

             });
     }

     ];
}
```

Still scrolls to top

Comment: I dont think I was clear. I meant my tableview automatically goes to the top cell by itself.  I'm trying to prevent this.  So a user can continue scrolling through the new entries on the next page

Comment: then you want to scroll at bottom means your last cell ?

Comment: yes to the last cell. when the user swipes down on table and next page is requested.  have tableview stay and show next page.

Comment: Did you use paging for show your data ? and ya in my answer check your tableview go to your last cell check my updated answer

Comment: Nice that makes sense. Let me try it and confirm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40042923/3548469

Comment: i just got this exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (39) beyond bounds (20) for section (0).'

Comment: @Dev_Tandel I tried adding that and it allows me to scroll further but still scrolls to top

Comment: @mparrish91 did you try my updated code ?

Comment: Yeah I need to play with that more. I got that exception. Seems like i need to time it

Comment: @mparrish91 with mine code your tableview scroll goes to bottom of your tableview last cell if you want to give position after some data added then create indexpath as your requirement .

Comment: @mparrish91 -  Then something should be wrong i am using with my 2 chat application and its is working awesome. Lets dig it futhur.

Comment: @dev_tandel play with the repo?  I find that can be easier sometime. Here is link https://github.com/mparrish91/flix

Comment: Yes. let me check

Comment: Found the issue

Comment: @mparrish91 did you solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting

```
[self.moviesTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height)];
```

in your `addSearchBar` method which is being called after load more completed, setting content offset at initial point.

Do also manage you `setupInfiniteScrollView` Where you are adding subview into Tableview.

And there is little bit changes with the logic

fetch this old y offset position

```
CGFloat oldOffset = self.moviesTableView.contentOffset.y;
```

Set the same Y position after load more like

```
CGPoint new = CGPointMake(0, oldOffset);
 [self.moviesTableView setContentOffset:new];
```

Comment: i am not getting you

Comment: Thank you this fixed it for me.  Dumb error of setting the content offset elsewhere.  I did not notice that didLayoutSubviews was called multiple times on table scroll.  In layoutSubviews I had awn addSearchBar function.  In it i offset my search bar at an initial point.

Answer (score 0):

Add line in your

```
if ([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]){
        NSLog(@"In main thread--completion handler");

       [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[YOURARRAY.count] - 1 inSection:0];
       [self.YOURTABLLENAME scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

       [self.loadingMoreView stopAnimating];
       [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic insertion of rows after receiving your data:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfInsertedIndexes = [NSMutableArray array]; 
NSInteger currentCount = self.yourOldData.count; 
for (int i =0; i < yourNewData.count; i++) 
{ 
      [arrayOfInsertedIndexes addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentCount+i inSection:0]];
}
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arrayOfInsertedIndexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Do not use

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: You have update your answer with arrayOfInsertedIndexes value.

Comment: The arrayofinsertedindexes is just the new data not the entire data array?

Comment: @mparrish91 take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after reloadData contentSize doesn't change synchronous. You should call layoutIfNeeded after reloadData. And only after that contentSize changed

Try this

```
//.....
 if ([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]){
     NSLog(@"In main thread--completion handler");

     CGFloat oldOffset = self.moviesTableView.contentSize.height;
     [self.moviesTableView reloadData];
     [self.moviesTableView layoutIfNeeded];
     CGFloat onewOffset = self.moviesTableView.contentSize.height;
     CGPoint new = CGPointMake(0, onewOffset - oldOffset);

     [self.moviesTableView setContentOffset:new];
     [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
     [self.loadingMoreView stopAnimating];
     [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
//.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective C:

```
 NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumberHere inSection:sectionNumberHere];
[theTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Swift:

```
 let offset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height + self.FOOTERHEIGHT);
 self.tableView.contentOffset = offset;
```